# Windows command bypassing Sandboxie

Tags: windows, sandbox

Using Sandboxie typing `net user some_user some_password`, on a sandboxed cmd, actually changes the password of the real user. Is this intentional?

It is just a default Sandboxie installation running on Windows 10 1903. I ran cmd by right-clicking the shortcut and selecting "Run with Sandboxie"

Comment: And does the command window come up sandboxed?

Comment: @schroeder Yes it is yellow, any normal software I execute runs sandboxed, and it is listed in the sandboxed programs currently running.

Comment: which  version you were using? i just tested on sandboxie plus 5.55 and i get Access is denied.